# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$get') when using axios in onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, vuex

I want to execute an axios request after the `onAuthStateChanged` hook in my VueX store:

```js
export const actions = {
  async onAuthStateChanged({ commit }, { authUser }) {
    if (authUser) {
      const test = await this.$axios.$get("/api/v1/products");
      console.log(test);
      const { uid, email } = authUser;
      commit("setUser", { uid, email });
      Cookies.set("auth-status", "authorized");
    } else {
      commit("cleanUser");
      Cookies.remove("auth-status");
    }
  },
  async login(_, { email, password }) {
    try {
      await this.$fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.message;
    }
  },
```

This however gives me a

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$get')
```

In another VueX store module i call my axios requests using the same way:

```
export const actions = {
  async fetchAllProducts({ commit }) {
    try {
      const products = await this.$axios.$get("/api/v1/products");
      commit("setProducts", products);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
}
```

Which works fine. This makes me steer towards the `onAuthStateChanged` hook not accepting axios for some reason.

Comment: The issue is probably not located here. Did you checked your module in `nuxt.config.js`? `onAuthStateChanged` is a Vuex action, right?

Comment: @kissu, no onAuthStateChanged is a firebase hook: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged

Comment: Where even is it located so? Do you have Nuxt context in there?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `$axios` (from the deconstructed argument) instead of `this.$axios`?

Comment: @samthecodingman this is the same at the end. At least, I doubt `onAuthStateChanged` is working like `asyncData` with no Nuxt context aka `this`.

Comment: Please check my edits to my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing **`$axios`** as a *function argument* in the line below:

```js
async onAuthStateChanged({ commit, $axios }, { authUser }) {
```

In the line below, `$axios` can be referenced as a *context variable*, and hence the error

```js
const test = await this.$axios.$get("/api/v1/products");
```

To resolve this, please modify it to:

```js
const test = await $axios.$get("/api/v1/products");
```

Comment: Check my edit to the question